# Event when entry's xview changes

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a simple program using `Tkinter`. I want a function to be called every time `xview` property of `entry` changes. But there doesn't seem to be an event like this, at least not one that I can find.

The `<Configure>` event fires only on resize, which I already handled, but it doesn't fire when actual value I'm tracking changes in a different way, such as the user dragging his mouse to see the end of the entry.

Here is the code:

```
import Tkinter as Tk
import tkFileDialog

root = Tk.Tk()

class RepositoryFolderFrame(Tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.build_gui()

        self.set_entry_text("Searching...")
        #root.after(0, self.find_repo)

        self.prev_entry_index = len(self.entry.get())
        root.bind("<Configure>", self.on_entry_resize)
        #self.entry.bind(???, self.on_entry_change)
        #self.entry.bind("<Configure>", self.on_entry_change)

    def on_entry_resize(self, event):
        cur_entry_index = self.entry.xview()[1]
        if cur_entry_index != self.prev_entry_index:
            self.entry.xview(self.prev_entry_index)

    def on_entry_change(self, event):
        # This should be called when xview changes...
        cur_entry_index = self.entry.xview()[1]
        self.prev_entry_index = cur_entry_index

    def set_entry_text(self, text):
        self.entry_text.set(text)
        self.entry.xview("end")

    def build_gui(self):
        label = Tk.Label(self, text = "Repository folder:")
        label.pack(side = Tk.LEFT)
        self.label = label

        entry_text = Tk.StringVar()
        self.entry_text = entry_text

        entry = Tk.Entry(self, width = 50, textvariable = entry_text)
        entry.configure(state = 'readonly')
        entry.pack(side = Tk.LEFT, fill = Tk.X, expand = 1)
        self.entry = entry

        button = Tk.Button(self, text = "Browse...")
        button.pack(side = Tk.LEFT)
        self.button = button

repo_frame = RepositoryFolderFrame(root)
repo_frame.pack(fill = Tk.X, expand = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What. is. `RepositoryFolderFrame`???

Comment: A class that inherits from `Tkinter.Frame`, as you can see in the code? Basically, just a wrapper for 3 widgets and functions that are related to them.

Comment: Ah, I see, you have created this class. But why did it give me an error...

Comment: `AttributeError: 'RepositoryFolderFrame' object has no attribute 'find_repo'`

Comment: Seems like you have forgotten to define `find_repo`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't realize I didn't strip that part of code. I will edit it. The actual code is longer and not related to the question, so I stripped it.

Comment: After adding code to a question, you should always copy and past the code from the answer into a new file and try to run it.

Comment: @BryanOakley I usually do that, but didn't this time for some reason..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mechanism for getting notified when the xview changes. There are ways to do it by modifying the underlying tcl code, but it's much more difficult than it's worth.

A simple solution is to write a function that polls the xview every few hundred milliseconds. It can keep track of the most recent xview, compare it to the current, and if it has changed it can fire off a custom event (eg: `<<XviewChanged>>`) which you can bind to.

It would look something like this:

```
class RepositoryFolderFrame(Tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        ...
        self.entry.bind("<<XviewChanged>>", self.on_entry_change)

        # keep a cache of previous xviews. A dictionary is
        # used in case you want to do this for more than 
        self._xview = {}
        self.watch_xview(self.entry)

    def watch_xview(self, widget):
        xview = widget.xview()
        prev_xview = self._xview.get(widget, "")
        self._xview[widget] = xview
        if xview != prev_xview:
            widget.event_generate("<<XviewChanged>>")
        widget.after(100, self.watch_xview, widget)
```

You'll need to modify that for the edge case that the entry widget is destroyed, though you can handle that with a simple `try` around the code. This should be suitably performant, though you might need to verify that if you have literally hundreds of entry widgets.

Comment: Ok, I can see that working. How about binding a mouse click + mouse move event on the entry? The entry is read-only, so is there another way to move the xview that I should be aware of?